# Flutter devices command says "Preparing iphone fore development"

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, flutter

I am trying to deploy my flutter app on an physical iphone device.

When I plug my iphone in to my lapto, I get the following message when I run 'flutter devices'...

```
Error: deviphone is busy: Preparing deviphone for development. Xcode will continue when deviphone is finished. (code -10)
```

This error message has been shown for a long time now, I don't think any progress is being made and the process is just hung. How can I progress past this point to actually use the iphone to deploy my flutter app on?

EDIT: I have tried restarting both macbook and iphone, and I have updated the iphone to the latest ios version, and have updated my xcode to the latest version as well. The problem still persists.

Comment: I would just restart the device and try again :D

Comment: I did try that. Updating post.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

1. Check the device's status in Xcode's run destination menu<sup>1</sup>. If a comment is shown in brackets, please attach a screenshot to your question.
2. Check if developer mode is enabled on your device. For this, go to Settings → Privacy & Security → Developer mode. Turn it on if it is not already.<sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/running-your-app-in-simulator-or-on-a-device 
<sup>2</sup> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/enabling-developer-mode-on-a-device